# Value of $x_{k+1}$ and errors in the Kalman filter

Tags: statistics, kalman-filter

I am learning Kalman filter so I have a doubt with respect to the state $x_{k+1}$, I have the following linear system,

\begin{align}
x_{k+1} & = Ax_{k} + w_{k} \\
y_{k} & = Cx_{k} + v_{k}
\end{align}

Where $w_{k}$ and $v_{k}$ are the acceleration force and the error measure of the GPS repectively, both of them with mean $0$ and covariance matrix Q and R respectively. I don't have a control vector. I read the derivation of the Kalman filter where in my case it summarise to the following equations

\begin{align}
\hat{x}_{k+1|k} & = A\hat{x}_{k|k} \tag{1} \\
P_{k+1|k} & = AP_{k|k}A^{T} + Q \tag{2} \\
\hat{x}_{k+1|k+1} & = \hat{x}_{k+1|k} + K(k+1)[y_{k+1} - C \hat{x}_{k+1|k}] \tag{3} \\ K(k+1) & = P_{k+1|k}C^{T}[CP_{k+1|k}C^{T} + R]^{-1} \tag{4} \\
P_{k+1|k+1} & = [I - K(k+1)C]P_{k+1|k} \tag{5}
\end{align}

Where $Q =  \Sigma_{acceleration}$, $R =  \Sigma_{GPSerror}$ are the covariance matrices and $\hat{x}_{k|k}$, $P_{k|k}$ are the mean and covariance matrix of the random vector $x_{k} \approx N(\hat{x}_{k|k}, P_{k|k})$ respectively, also $\hat{x}_{k|k}$ is the mean of $x_{k}$ given $y_{k}$, so $\hat{x}_{k|k-1}$ is the mean of $x_{k}$ given $y_{k-1}$ the same for $P_{k|k}$.

My doubt is, to know $y_{k+1}$ in $(3)$ I need to know $x_{k+1}$ that can be derived from $(1)$, the problem is when I am in a state greater than 1, I don't know the variable $x_{k}$ so I use $\hat{x}_{k|k}$ instead of $x_{k}$ also to predict $w_{k}$ and $v_{k}$ due to $w_{k} \approx N(0,Q)$  and $v_{k} \approx N(0,R)$, I substitude them by a sample of its distribution respectively. Can anyone explain me if I am wrong and what's the error in the prediction of perform this substitutions?

Comment: For equation $(3)$ you can also just lower the indices by one, so all $k+1$ and $k$ would become $k$ and $k-1$ respectively. And what do you mean by "to predict $w_k$ and $v_k$"? You shouldn't add those samples to any of the equations $(1)$ to $(5)$ or are you talking about simulating the system that generates the signal $y_k$?

Comment: I am taking $\hat{x}_{k|k}$ and $P_{k|k}$ as the mean and covariance matrix of the random vector $x_{k} \approx N(\hat{x}_{k|k}, P_{k|k})$ respectively, also $\hat{x}_{k|k}$ is the mean of $x_{k}$ given $y_{k}$ as you can see in $(3)$, my question is How can I get $y_{k}$?

Comment: $y_k$ is a measurement from the system with state vector $x_k$. For example if you have an electronic motor with encoder on its shaft as the system, then every sample time the encoder would give you a noisy measurement of the angular position of the motorshaft.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand. I have understood the following, if the GPS sends me data each second and I want to predict the following 2 minutes. Do I must wait at least 2 minutes to get the measurements $y_{k}$, from $y_{1}$ to $y_{120}$? Cannot I predict it during the development of the kalman filter?

Comment: Yes, but only using the prediction steps, so only repeat $(1)$ and $(2)$. The indices of $\hat{x}$ would also change, because you only have information of $y_k$. For example $n$ prediction steps would give $\hat{x}_{k+n|k}$.

Comment: Do you mean that if I do not know the observations $y_{k}$ my Kalman filter will be reduced to the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, but if I know it, I will have to wait until get the necessary number of data?